# CPython and GCC

Tags: python

If I start python under MacOS X 10.8 in the console it starts with "Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[**GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang** 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin".

In what way does the implementation of python depend on GCC?

Comment: The python infrastructure (notably its runtime, including its garbage collector) is compiled with some C compiler, and that is GCC or Clang. And you need a C compiler to code extensions for python (usually `dlopen`-ed shared objects).

Comment: I don't udnerstand the downvotes. It is a valid question, probably out of curiosity.

Comment: @glglgl, +1. It sounds like a genuine question. I have now upvoted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python is implemented *in* C, and records what version of the C compiler was used to compile it (to aid tracking down compiler-specific bugs).

The implementation itself does not vary based on the compiler. It *can* vary based on the platform it is compiled for, and the available external libraries, but there is nothing altering Python behaviour based on the compiler used.